# Decoding multiple JSON URL's using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube API to try and place JSON data from multiple URL's into a mySQL database. I'm trying to use the json decoder on multiple JSON links and at the moment my code removes the first array and overwrites it with the second. Please note that I do not want to use the array_merge function as I want to use around 6-7 json URLs. If you could be pretty specific that would be great too, as I'm very new to php.

```
$linkone = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId={playlistID}&key={Key}';
$linktwo = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId={PlaylistID}&key={Key}';


$content = file_get_contents($linkone);
$content2 = file_get_contents($linktwo);

$json = json_decode($content, true);


foreach($json['items'] as $row)
{
$title = $row['snippet']['title'];
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$description = $row['snippet']['description'];
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);

$publishedAt = $row['snippet']['publishedAt'];
$publishedAt = mysql_real_escape_string($publishedAt);
$high = $row['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url'];
$high = mysql_real_escape_string($high);

$sql = "INSERT INTO table(title, description, publishedAt, high) VALUES('".$title."','".$description."','".$publishedAt."','".$high."')";

if(!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
{
die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
}
}
```

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Why don't you put your links into an array and then put your JSON processing code into a separate function and call it for each URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
$linkone = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId={playlistID}&key={Key}';
$linktwo = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId={PlaylistID}&key={Key}';

$jsonArray = array(
  json_decode(file_get_contents($linkone)),
  json_decode(file_get_contents($linktwo))
);

foreach($jsonArray as $json) {
  foreach($json['items'] as $row)
  {
    $title = $row['snippet']['title'];
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
    $description = $row['snippet']['description'];
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);

    $publishedAt = $row['snippet']['publishedAt'];
    $publishedAt = mysql_real_escape_string($publishedAt);
    $high = $row['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url'];
    $high = mysql_real_escape_string($high);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table(title, description, publishedAt, high)
      VALUES('".$title."','".$description."','".$publishedAt."','".$high."')";

    if(!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
    {
      die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I receive this error though... "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array." I'm guessing it's something to do with "true" part not being included?

Comment: Yes add `true` as the second parameter in the json_decode

Comment: O yeah, sorry I forgot.